# "must be member of role" error raises when try to set one user access to another user objects

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

On google cloud, with "postgres" user (which is not superuser), i do:

```
CREATE ROLE postgres_subuser1 LOGIN PASSWORD 'some_pass';
CREATE ROLE postgres_subuser2 LOGIN PASSWORD 'some_pass';

GRANT postgres TO postgres_subuser1;
GRANT postgres TO postgres_subuser2;
```

Above part wroks, though then I try to set users access on each other objects:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres_subuser1 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO postgres_subuser2; 
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres_subuser2 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO postgres_subuser1;
```

gives: `must be member of role "postgres_subuser1"`

How can solve that?

BTW, if try same on local instance, it works without any error, but this error raises on google cloud.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to explicitly grant the `postgres` user the role. Eg:

```
GRANT postgres_subuser1 TO postgres;
```

Comment: so instead of `GRANT postgres TO postgres_subuser1;` I need `GRANT postgres_subuser1 TO postgres;` ?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve, but in order to allow the postgres user to alter the default privileges for the postgres_subuser1 user then yes, otherwise it doesn't have permission to do so (this wouldn't be true if it was a true superuser, but is the case in gcp managed postgres)